# Excel SumIf / CountIf etc wont work properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an issue with my sumif excel formula. For some reason , it wont work properly. Context: here my excel data :

[image]

When i use this formula:  "=SUMIF(A3:A6,"TT",B3:B6)", i got 0 everytime. I can change the data format , the sheet , the content or even the data itself , it changes nothing , always 0. Halp :'(

Comment: I get 5. Are you sure your data are in the right cells? Also, you're not wrapping the formula in double quotes in excel, are you?

Comment: Nope , of course!  When i use the formula , i just click on the range to be sure i dont type the wrong cells ! So its not it :/ . I dont understand cause other simple formulas  like SUM for example , work properly .

Comment: Perhaps one or more of your entries in column B is not actually a number, but a number stored as text. Test them with =ISNUMBER(B2), etc., which should return TRUE if they are numerics.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no spaces or any other "hidden" whitespace alongside your data in column A. Delete the contents of the cell and re-type it to make sure.

Also make sure you have auto calculations turned on - File -> Options -> Formulas -> Workbook Calculation set to Automatic

Comment: These are suggestions; this should have been a comment.

Comment: Thanks Steve. It was actually the problem. My main problem now is that i have a 400 datalines that i want to sumif but how can i delete those "hidden" whitespace ?

Comment: If it is just spaces, put the following into a separate column:
=TRIM(A3) and drag it down to remove all the spaces, then copy and paste as values back to column A.

If it's other whitespace then it's more tricky, and I would normally use a custom VBA function. This would probably warrant its own question.

Comment: Select the column then Data ► Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width, Finish repairs trailing spaces faster but it doesn't account for non-breaking spaces (typical from a web page copy).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the formula, it might be worth checking the values in column A for any trailing spaces.

Comment: This is a suggestion; this should have been a comment fwiw, I do appreciate your recognition of right-aligned numbers and left-aligned text. You just haven't offered a solution.